# C++ INET noob, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, sockets

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int port, n,sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
  struct hostent *serv;

  char buffer[256];

  if(argc<3)
  {
    cout <<"\n ussage: host port\nexiting\n";
    return 0;
  }

  port=atoi(argv[2]);

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockfd < 0)
  {
    cout <<"\nsocket creation on"<<port<<" failed\nexiting\ncheck to see if port is in use";
    return 0;
  }

  serv = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  if (serv=NULL)
  {
    cout <<"\n"<<serv<<" is not a valid host name\nexiting";
    return 0;
  }

  bzero((char *) &srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr));

  srv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

  bcopy((char *) serv->h_addr, 
        (char *) &srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
                 serv->h_length);

  srv_addr.sin_port=htons(port); 
  if (connect(sockfd,&srv_addr,
               sizeof (srv_addr))<0)
  {
    cout <<" \nconnection failed\n";
  }

  cout <<"\nType message\n";

  bzero(buffer, 256);

  cin.getline(buffer,256);

  n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
  if (n>0)
  {
    cout <<"\nsocket write error\nexiting\n";
  }

  n=read(sockfd,buffer,255);


  if (n>0)
  {
    cout <<"\nsocket read error\nexiting\n";
  }           

  cout <<buffer;

  return 0;
}
```

When compiled, I get this error:

```
fg.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
fg.c:53:33: error: cannot convert ‘sockaddr_in*’ to ‘const sockaddr*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int connect(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t)’
```

I cant figure it out. I am a noob to programming. Any help is grateful.

Comment: Could you please properly format/indent your code? That will make it far easier to follow what you've been writing.

Comment: I thought I did. Thats how new ...or out of it I am. Use to code simple little c++ codes when I was in my teens.

Comment: Thanks Arrowdodger. I realized it was referring to my structure as I asked you that 2nd question.

Comment: @ Bart- Ok, I see, I didnt realize it did not paste the same as I copied out of emacs. Will do for now on.

Answer (score 1):

You need explicit cast. Replace

```
connect(sockfd,&srv_addr, sizeof (srv_addr))
```

with

```
connect(sockfd,(sockaddr*)&srv_addr, sizeof (srv_addr))
```

Comment: Do I need to declare sockaddr, or is this something I have already declared under a different name.

Comment: You continue declaring your `srv_addr` variable as a `sockaddr_in`, but you type-cast it as a `sockaddr` when calling `connect()`, just like arrowdodger showed you.  `sockaddr` is declared in the same header file as `sockaddr_in`.